# Why wont this program allow me to divide

Tags: java

I noticed I could not find the digits in really large numbers. I decided to use biginteger to solve this problem however it will not let me divide them. I  also turned one of the divisions into the big int dividion method but still it gives me a red flag. can anyone help me figure out why this is happening? the divide method is not working also. I changed one division to the divide method and left the rest as regular divisions.

```
//This class test the recursive method to see how many digits are in a number
public class TestDigits {

public static void main(String[] args) {// main method to test the nmbDigits method
    Scanner c = new Scanner(System.in);
    try{
    System.out.println("Input an integer number:");
     BigInteger number = c.nextBigInteger() ;
    System.out.println(nmbDigits(number));}
    catch (InputMismatchException ex){
    System.out.println("incorrect input, integer values only.");
System.exit(1);}}


static BigInteger nmbDigits(BigInteger c) {//nmbDigits method takes input from user and returns the number of digits
    int digits = 0;
    if (c.divide(10) == 0){
        digits++;}
      else if (c / 10 != 0){
        digits++;
        BigInteger count = c/10;
        do {
            count = count/10;
            digits++;}
          while (count != 0);}
    return digits;}
}
```

Comment: Fyi, you could just cast the integer to a string and get the length of it, to get the number of digits.

Comment: the purpose of the project is a recursive method...........

Comment: Well, no offence, but you should look up recursive methods again. `nmbDigits` isn't recursive. A recursive method makes calls to itself.

Answer (score 6):

You can't use the division operator `/` on instances of `BigInteger`. This operator only works for primitive numerical types. That's why the `BigInteger` class has a `divide` method.

`BigInteger result = c.divide(new BigInteger("10"));` would work.

Comment: @user3602515 The divide method accepts a BigInteger parameter and returns a BigInteger. You are not using it correctly.

Comment: so i cannot divide big numbers by a little number? so i am limited to finding the digits of smaller numbers less than 10 digits long?

Comment: @user3602515 You'd have to convert the little number to `BigInteger` first.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestDigits {

public static void main(String[] args) {// main method to test the nmbDigits method
    Scanner c = new Scanner(System.in);
    try{
    System.out.println("Input an integer number:");
     BigInteger number = c.nextBigInteger() ;
    System.out.println(nmbDigits(number));}
    catch (InputMismatchException ex){
    System.out.println("incorrect input, integer values only.");
System.exit(1);}}


static BigInteger nmbDigits(BigInteger c) {//nmbDigits method takes input from user and returns the number of digits
    long digits = 0;
    if (c.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(10L)) == BigInteger.valueOf(0L)){
        digits++;}
      else if (c.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(10L)) != BigInteger.valueOf(0L)){
        digits++;
        long count = (c.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(10L))).longValue();
        do {
            count = count/10;
            digits++;}
          while (count != 0);}
    return BigInteger.valueOf(digits);}
}
```